# RubyMine with rbenv gemset

Tags: ruby, rubymine, rbenv, rbenv-gemset

RubyMine deals with rvm gemset feature but after some research looks like it does not work with rbenv gemset plugin.

Should I use the same *~/.gemrc* file to specify the GEM PATH to indicate rbenv gemset? There is some other way to work with RubyMine and rbenv gemsets? or should I install other gems when working with RubyMine? What is the best practice?

Thanks for any direction about this issue.

Comment: [Check this page](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/rbenv-support.html) for the requirements. Note that you [need to have `Gemfile`](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/ruby-gems-support.html) in the project root for RubyMine to detect gems.

Comment: I can use RubyMine with multiple ruby versions in rbenv, but it does not understand gemset directories as it does with rvm. Thanks for the reference though!

Answer (score 1):

Please vote for this feature request:

- [RUBY-12839](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-12839) Support for rbenv-gemset